# Passar Array como parâmetro em VBA (Excel)

Tags: excel-vba

Como faço para passar um Array como parâmetro para uma função em VBA?
Detalhe se eu definir um tipo de variável como String, Integer, etc... funciona, entretanto um tipo definido por mim, não funciona!
Por exemplo:

```
Type pessoa
    nome As String
    idade As Integer
End Type

Public Sub SomaIdade(arrPessoa As Variant)
    Dim soma As Integer
    For i = 0 To UBound(arrPessoa)
        soma = som + arrPessoa(i)
    Next i
    Debug.Print (soma)
End Sub

Sub main()
    Dim p(2) As pessoa
    p(0).idade = 10
    p(1).idade = 20
    p(2).idade = 30

    SomaIdade (p)
End Sub
```

Comment: Dei uma pesquisada e parece que não tem como.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você estava com um problema de sintaxe, pois você não quer passar um array, mas sim o tipo definido pelo usuário `pessoa`, veja os códigos a seguir:

**Função**

```
Public Type pessoa
    Nome As String
    Idade As Long
End Type

Public Function SomaIdade(ByRef arrPessoa() As pessoa)
    Dim soma As Long
    For i = 0 To UBound(arrPessoa)
        soma = soma + arrPessoa(i).Idade
    Next i
    SomaIdade = soma
End Function

Sub main()
    Dim p() As pessoa
    Dim soma_idade As Long
    ReDim p(0 To 2)
    p(0).Idade = 10
    p(1).Idade = 20
    p(2).Idade = 30


    soma_idade = SomaIdade(p())
    Debug.Print soma_idade
End Sub
```

**Sub**

```
Public Type pessoa
    Nome As String
    Idade As Long
End Type

Public Sub SomaIdade(ByRef arrPessoa() As pessoa)
    Dim soma As Long
    For i = 0 To UBound(arrPessoa)
        soma = soma + arrPessoa(i).Idade
    Next i
    Debug.Print (soma)
End Sub

Sub main()
    Dim p() As pessoa
    ReDim p(0 To 2)
    p(0).Idade = 10
    p(1).Idade = 20
    p(2).Idade = 30

    SomaIdade p()
End Sub
```

Comment: Funcionou, muito obrigado!
Passei 4hs tentando resolver esse problema, agora que você resolveu, parece a coisa mais obvia do mundo rsrsrs, faz parte!